# How to get just the currently set CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, css

An unstyled `div` element already has several CSS declarations by default. For example:

```
cursor:auto;
display:block;
float:none;
font-size:16px;
```

(and several other statements)

**Note the example below:**

```js
document.querySelector('.div1').style.padding = '20px';
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" style="border-radius: 5px;">word</div>
```

How can I get only the styles that have been defined in the stylesheet and JavaScript, ignoring all other default declarations?

I would like to get the following output:

```
background-color: skyblue;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 20px;
```

Comment: also the default styles are defined in a stylesheet, they are just set in the default stylesheet.

Comment: Perhaps you can destructure the style object inside an element:
`var {backgroundColor, borderRadius, padding} = element.style;`

Then you would be able to use `backgroundColor`, `borderRadius` and `padding` as variables inside your JS.

I think you will get the styles in JS which the browser applies to the particular element. Browsers apply styles by the following rules in css specificity: https://yogeshchauhan.com/what-are-css-specificity-rules-and-how-does-browser-apply-them/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking through the element's `style` and [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets), we can find the names of all CSS properties that were set. Then, we can get the values of those properties using [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```js
function getAllDefinedStyles(elem) {
  const props = new Set([...elem.style]);
  for (const {cssRules} of document.styleSheets) {
    for (const rule of cssRules) {
      if (elem.matches(rule.selectorText)) {
        for (const prop of rule.style) {
          props.add(prop);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const computed = getComputedStyle(elem);
  return Object.fromEntries([...props]
      .map(prop => [prop, computed.getPropertyValue(prop)]));
}
console.log(getAllDefinedStyles(document.querySelector('.div1')));
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" style="border-radius: 5px;">word</div>
<script>
  document.querySelector('.div1').style.padding = '20px';
</script>
```